# Convert DT.Rows(0).item to DateTime String MM/dd/YYYY

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Hi i am pulling the date from sql server which returns this:  12/19/2014 4:17:31 PM

However I only want it to return 12/19/2014

I am using this to get the order date: `txtOrderDate.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("OrderDate")`

How do I convert this to only return the date in this format MM/dd/YYYY?

I cannot do it using the SQL Statement because I am pulling other columns as well.

Thanks

Comment: Cast/convert `dt.Rows(0).Item("OrderDate")` to a .Net Framework [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx), then call [.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf(v=vs.110).aspx) and format as desired.

Comment: Pulling other columns has nothing to do with it: you could still format just this column the way you want. Whether you _should_ do this in the sql code is another issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* this will work:

```
txtOrderDate.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("OrderDate").ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

However, it's been a while since I've had to work with DataTable cells directly; there's a chance the above code will only have the `Object` type, rather than the VB.Net `DateTime` type, and therefore that `.ToString()` overload won't be available. If that's the case, do this instead:

```
txtOrderDate.Text = DirectCast(dt.Rows(0).Item("OrderDate"), DateTime).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get the output desidered with

```
Dim dt as DateTime
if Not dt.Rows(0).IsNull("OrderDate") _ 
   AndAlso DateTime.TryParse(dt.Rows(0).Item("OrderDate"), _
           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, _
           DateTimeStyles.None, dt) Then
    txtOrderDate.Text = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
else
    .... ' Something to do in case of null or invalid date
End If
```

The use of DataRow.IsNull and DateTime.TryParse is a precautionary step to avoid any possible exception in case your column "OrderDate" is null or not in a correct format.

Comment: Nice use of try parse and pre checking if its not null! + 1